# Working with bridge entities in DBMS

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

So I'm making a project which requires us to use bridge entities.  I've made a simple design (though I can't show it to you).

**tblStudent**
 *- (PK) Student_ID
 - LastName
 - FirstName
 - MiddleName
 - YearLevel
 - Section
 - Adviser
 - CellphoneNumber*

**tblGets [bridge]**
 *- (PK) Student_ID
 - (PK) OffenseCode*

**tblOffense**
 *- (PK) OffenseCode
 - OffenseDescription
 - OffenseCategory*

i have managed to INNER JOIN my tables except for tblGets which I don't know where I will incorporate in my project.  Because my project keeps track of the offenses a student commits in school.

Can anyone help me where I should incorporate tblGets in my project? Because it seems like it's out of place when it fact it isn't.

Comment: ... *where I should incorporate tblGets* ... Just like any other table. What is your exact problem? You seem to be doing pretty well. All you have said looks correct. Go ahead, just `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Your data model describes what it needs to. Usually you would have an app that lets you input the data and some reports that pull it out again. So you 'incorporate tblGets'... to enable that. You need to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Bridge entity is useful to manage a many-to-many relationship.

If one particular offense could be committed by multiple students, then it makes sense to keep the table.

*CASE 1*: In you application, you can list all Offences by school:

```
SELECT 
    OffenseDescription,
    OffenseCategory,
    Student_ID,
    LastName,
    FirstName
FROM tblOffense O
LEFT JOIN tblGets G ON G.OffenseCode = O.OffenseCode
LEFT JOIN tblStudent S ON S.Student_ID = G.Student_ID
WHERE O.School_ID = 23
```

The result could be as following:

> Serch result for School 23:
>
> - A gang robbery at 2017-01-02
>
>   - Bob Sand
>   - Tim Mitch
> - Walking on the lawn at 2017-03-12
>
>   - Antony Brown

*CASE 2*: When you show information for a particular offense, you can give references to each related student.

*CASE 3*: Show some statistic for the student, who was his/her accomplice in the most cases, to identify destructive friendship:

```
SELECT
    AccS.Student_ID,
    AccS.FirstName,
    AccS.LastName,
    COUNT(*) AS Amount
FROM tblOffense O
JOIN tblGets G ON G.OffenseCode = O.OffenseCode
JOIN tblStudent S ON S.Student_ID = G.Student_ID
JOIN tblGets AccG
    ON AccG.OffenseCode = O.OffenseCode
    AND AccG.Student_ID <> S.Student_ID -- looking for accomplices
JOIN tblStudent AccS
    ON AccS.Student_ID = AccG.Student_ID
WHERE
    S.Student_ID = @ParticularStudentId
GROUP BY AccS.Student_ID, AccS.FirstName, AccS.LastName
ORDER BY Amount DESC
```